# Tesseract to do OCR on images with bold text

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I am struggling to get the text from the image where the text is bold. I have attached the image here.[image: Original Image]

I have inverted the color of the image using OpenCV and changed it to [image: Inverted color]

I want the tesseract to give 5 as text output, but I get an empty value.

Image with text in multiple lines. The data from this image is not been extracted using psm 7,8 or 9.
[image: Multiline text image]

Comment: I changed the page segmentation mode (PSM) to 7 and it works. I am not sure what happened internally. My struggle now is how do I identify on the fly which psm I need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Both images can be recognized with `psm` set to `7`, `8`, or `9`. Would suggest to use Tesseract 4.0.0 alpha for improved OCR result if you are using 3.x.x, and use `--psm 9`.

```
Page segmentation mode:
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
```

Hope this help.

**EDIT:**

Regarding your additional question on on-the-fly to identify which psm to use, you may check the image height to determine the `psm` value to be used.

For example, the height of the `5` one is 80 and the `fox` message is 480. With the pixel value, it's easier to implement a code to set the `psm` value.

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)
I am doing OCR on multiple images. If for some other image I have text in multiple lines then how do I identify on the fly for which image I use what psm.

Comment: @kant01 Can you EDIT your post to include a image sample with multiple lines?

Comment: @kant01 Just saw your EDIT (there is no inbox message as you haven't added comment with attention to me by @...). Anyway, I have updated my answer. Have a look and `tick` the answer if it helps.

Comment: what's the exact difference for psm 7 and 8? it's also related to the height of the characters?

Comment: @Wesley psm 8 will only output a character form the input. Both these psm are optimized for its specific type of recognition. Basically, the psm is not directly related to the height of the characters.